# Adding character just to end and beginning of file in shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a bunch of large matrices that I need to reformat, ideally using the shell.

Suppose I have this content stored in example.csv:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
5,6,7
```

Then I do

```
cat example.csv | tr ',' ' ' | awk '{print "["$0"]"}'
```

to get

```
[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]
```

But I need my final format to look as such

```
[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [5 6 7]]
```

So how do I accomplish this using the shell with e.g. sed, awk or something similar? I.e. prepending `[` to the beginning of the example and appending `]` to the last line of the example?

Imagine that my .csv matrices have several thousand columns and rows.

Comment: How crucial are the leading spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just awk can handle this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "["} NR>1{print ""} {$1=$1; printf "[%s]", $0} 
       END {print "]"}' example.csv
[[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]]
```

- `BEGIN` - Print `[` without newline
- `-F,` Use comma as field separator
- `$1=$1` Change something to tell awk to format output differently using `OFS` (space by default)
- `NR>{print ""}` - Print newline for record # 2 onwards
- `END` - Print `]` and newline

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you are interested in `sed` solution

```
$ sed '1 s/^/[/; s/.*/[&]/; $ s/$/]/; s/,/ /g' input
[[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` (read the file twice)

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a=NR;next}
         FNR==1 {$0="["$0} FNR==a {$0=$0"]"}
         {$1=$1;$0="["$0"]";print}' example.csv{,}
[[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[5 6 7]]
```